# How to fix color for the Likert data in R package HH?

Tags: r, plot, graph, colors, likert

I would like to assign colors according to my choice;

## data

```
resp <- data.frame(replicate(50, sample(1:7, 100, replace=TRUE)))
resp <- data.frame(lapply(resp, factor, ordered=TRUE, 
                levels=1:7, 
                labels=c("Missing","Not Applicable","Strongly disagree","Disagree", "Neutral","Agree","Strongly Agree")))

resp = t(apply(resp,2,table))[,levels(resp[,1])]
```

## plot likert

I don't want to use diverge_hcl or sequential_hcl.

```
library(HH)
myColor <- likertColor(nc=7, ReferenceZero=5)

plot.likert(resp,as.percent=TRUE,col=myColor)
```

[image: Likert Plot for example]

I have two columns extra named "Missing" and "Not Applicable". 
I need a color scheme that relates to the categories, such as:-

- Missing = "light grey"
- Not applicable = "Grey"
- Strongly Disagree = "Red"
- Disagree = "ligt red"
- Netural = "White" or "Yellow"
- Agree = "Light Blue"
- Strongly Agree = "Blue"

Is there any idea that how to apply above color scheme to my plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is :

```
  myColor <- c("light gray","gray","blue","light blue","white","pink","red")
  plot.likert(resp,as.percent=TRUE,col=myColor)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also possible using RGB in hex:

```
plot.likert(resp,as.percent=TRUE,
            col=c("#E94E1B", "#F7AA4E", "#BEBEBE", "#6193CE", "#00508C"))
```