Legend in Likert plot appear white instead of color in R
i have a data frame in R called df which is a subset of pisaitems data of likert package.
The problem i face is that when i plot the result of the likert function the legend of level "Agree" appear in white color because there are no data for this category.But i want this category-level to have a color.
df_plot <- likert(df) 
plot(df_plot)

Where the df is the below data :
structure(list(ST24Q01 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor"), ST24Q02 = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"
), class = "factor"), ST24Q03 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor"), ST24Q04 = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"
), class = "factor"), ST24Q05 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor"), ST24Q06 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"
), class = "factor"), ST24Q07 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor"), ST24Q08 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"
), class = "factor"), ST24Q09 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor"), ST24Q10 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"
), class = "factor"), ST24Q11 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor")), row.names = 68038:68087, class = "data.frame")

i receive :

all i want is o change the color of the agree level to something else.Let's say green. The problem is that the object df_plot is class of likert.
class(df_plot)
[1] "likert"

How can this thing change ?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32167573/7669319

@FelixJassler no because he/she is using HH package that has the same function likert() but takes different data frame structure input. My problem is specific to likert package.This package is that i use in real data.

Hm... I'm not sure I see the problem, is it not possible to set the col parameter inside plot()? (i.e., plot(df_plot, col=c('#d8b366', '#ebd9b1', '#acd8d4', 'red')))

@FelixJassler if you run it you will see again the color in the legend of the agree level is white.I know that there are no data for agree level.But nonetheless i want the legend to be colored appropriately

Have you tried adding a couple of 3L to the data to see if the Agree response is being rendered?

@FelixJassler yes is being rendered but this is not the case.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Which packages do you use?

@Quinten likert package

The issue seems to be related to a recent change in ggplot2 3.5.0 which now requires to explicitly set show.legend=TRUE inside the geom to show a legend key for unused factor levels and which apparently is not accounted for in likert.
But a fix would be to manually set show.legend=TRUE for the geom_bar layer used to draw the bars which is the third layer of the ggplot object returned by plot.likert():
library(likert)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: xtable

packageVersion("likert")
#> [1] '1.3.5'
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'

df_plot <- likert(df)
  
p <- plot(df_plot)

p$layers[[3]]$show.legend <- TRUE

p


